# How do I get something like repeat customers in Django

Tags: python, django

My models look something like this:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
   date = models.DateField()
   total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I then have a queryset of orders:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime(year=2009, month=6, day=1)
end_date = datetime(year=2009, month=11, day=1)
orders = Order.objects.filter(date__lte=end_date).filter(date__gte=start_date)
```

Now, I want to find out which customers made multiple orders between those times, how many orders they made, and what their average total is.  I get the feeling that I should be using Django 1.1's new aggregation features, but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

Always base your query around the object in which you are primarily interested in:

```
repeat_customers = Customer.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('order'))\
                                   .filter(order_count__gt=1)
```

Then if you want to annotate with their totals (you could alternatively do this in the annotation above, I'm just separating the code for readability):

```
repeat_customers = repeat_customers.annotate(avg_total=Avg('order__total'))
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense to me.  Now how would I restrict the orders annotated to only orders within my orders queryset?

Comment: Just string your filters together:
Customer.objects.annotate(order_count=Count('order')).filter(order_count__gt=1, date__lte=end_date, date__gte=start_date)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use for Django 1.1's [`annotate()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) functionality, which is part of [aggregateion](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation).  Specifically, you'll probably want to use the [`values()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) function.

Comment: right, so for the average order total, I'd do a query like Order.objects.values('customer').annotate(avg_total=Avg('total')), but how do I get the number of orders each customer has?

Comment: you can use `.count()` to get a count of the filtered queries.